# Android "OnTouchRelease" Event?

Tags: android, touch-event, tablerow

I have a TableRow with a custom background. When I click and hold my finger down, then drag out of the row and release without selecting anything (and thus generating a click event), the dark lines above and below the TableRow aren't being redrawn.

What even should I listen for, or, how might I refresh this Table so that the rows are redrawn if a touch is detected, but no selection is actually made?

Thanks everybody,

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect touch events (for a realease), can refer MotionEvent in Android, you have to override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)

You will get events for the Touch and then can match the action of the event (event.getAction) to ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP(for when touch is released)

```
Eg.
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //can check if selection is made or not and add function accordingly
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How many columns do you have in your table, depending on your requirement, you can look up the ListView and custom adapter implementation with a notifySetDataChanged...check:
    http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you. It took me a while to figure out where to implement this, but this is indeed the solution I needed. Thank you.